# Check if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$ is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Check if $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n^2})$ is convergent. 
I attempted to solve it like this: 
(1) Rationalize the numerator: $$a_n =\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$ 
(2) Compare this series with the harmonic series: 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \ge \frac{1}{n+n} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot\frac{1}{n}$$
Now, this is where my doubt started to arise - can I say that the series in question does disverge? I mean, does the fact that its partial sum is greater than half of the sum of the harmonic series mean that this sum does approach infinity?

Comment: Do you mean $a_n =\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{n^2}}$? Because that's what you get if you rationalise the numerator of $\sqrt{n^2 + 1} - \sqrt{n^2}$. It seems like that's what you're using in your calculations at any rate.

Comment: Actually if partial sums are rising and they are greater than $H_{n}$ for example. Then you could conclude that series diverges.

Comment: Your rationalization is either wrong or you typed it incorrectly.

Comment: Are you copying your "attempt" from some source? Because what you write is riddled with major typos...

Comment: The title and the first line in the question are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you have shown that each term in your sum is greater than $\frac12\frac1n$, then that means that each partial sum is greater than $\frac12H_n$, and since $H_n\to \infty$, we clearly have $\frac12H_n\to \infty$, which means that your series diverges.